# Getting error "No JSON provided" from Ogre when using post, but when use online converter same JSON is recognized

Tags: php, post, php-curl

I'm troubleshooting an issue trying to use Ogre to convert a GeoJSON to a Shapefile.

I was trying using php curl_exec, and also with Postman, and get the same response with each:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "msg": "No json provided"
}
```

However, when I paste the json into their web tool here, it successfully converts: https://ogre.adc4gis.com/

My php code looks like this:

```
           $posturl = "https://ogre.adc4gis.com/convertJson";
           $params = array('json'=>$geojson);
           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);         
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
           $streamVerboseHandle = fopen($CI->config->item('log_path').'curl_log.log', 'w+');
           cucurl_execrl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $streamVerboseHandle);
           $output = curl_exec($ch);
           curl_close($ch);
```

$params looks like this:

```
(
    [json] => {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.32271671155468,44.55490573909421]},"properties":{"fldOriginalCode":"CR","fldOriginalValue":"Colchester Reef","fldDescription":"Estimated location of Colchester Reef"}}]}
)
```

I'm not sure why I can't get it to convert using a post request?

Thank you!

Comment: `$params = json_encode($params,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` , perhaps? Also, when in doubt about the setup: https://reqbin.com/code/php/goecadht/php-curl-post-json-example

Comment: That page says request are asking for jsonUrl in addition to json, "jsonUrl - the URL for a remote GeoJSON file".

Comment: @Guesser, the page says to use with "one of the following params:" so not all are required.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, thanks!  I just tried that but got the same response.

Comment: What is the value of your `$out` variable? Is it a file of some sort? If so, can you post it as well (if it's reasonably sized, and there are no privacy issues, I mean). I mean this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);`

Comment: @FiddlingAway, $out is a file path on our server.  That part was correct- the issue ended up being that I was using an array for $params.  $params = array('json'=>$geojson); When I rewrote that just putting the JSON in directly it worked: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "json=$geojson");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up working with this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "json=$geojson");
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```